# Return value of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a point system (you can verify with a command to check if you completed a challenge, if so, the bot will give you points) for my discord.js bot. I can't find a way to check if the value is correct or not. The command looks like:

```
!verify <flag-name> <value>
```

Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const flag = {
 flag1: { value: 'test', points: 20 },
 flag2: { value: 'test2', points: 30 },
};

module.exports.run = async (client, message) => {
 let args = message.content.slice(4).split(' ');
 var keys = Object.keys(flag);

 keys.forEach((key) => {
  if (key == args[2]) {
   var str = JSON.stringify(keys);
   var result = JSON.parse(str);
   console.log(result['value']);
  }
 });
};
```

The problem is that `result['value']` always returns `undefined`, even when I know the flag name and value is valid.

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting an error or an unexpected output? What exactly is your question? Also, is the name of the challenge supposed to be the key name, like `flag1`? Or is it the value property, like `test1`.

Comment: I m getting undefined, and yes the challenge is supposed to be named flag1. And the value is in the value property

Comment: But you're checking the command against the value names, not the challenge names, right? Also, why are you splitting 4 characters when making the args variable- isn't `!verify ` 8 characters?

Comment: the command is !verify <challenge-name> <value-of-the-flag> because for each challenge you have a different number of points given. I m splitting 4 characters because the real prefix is sudo but I thought that it will be easier to understand with ! instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a value is correct using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const flag = {
 flag1: { value: 'test', points: 20 },
 flag2: { value: 'test2', points: 30 },
};

module.exports.run = async (client, message) => {
 // get the challenge and value using destructuring
 let [cmd, challenge, value] = message.content.slice(4).split(' ');

 // find the entry with both names matching the names given
 const result = Object.entries(flag).find(
  ([flag, data]) => flag === challenge && data.value === value
 );

 // provide an error if nothing is found
 if (!result)
  return message.channel.send('Not a valid value and/or flag');

 // do something with the points
 console.log(result[1].points)
};
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0rx5zth/)**